# Yahoo Gemini - Making PUT request

Tags: php, yahoo-api

I'm using  https://github.com/saurabhsahni/php-yahoo-oauth2/blob/master/YahooOAuth2.class.php

Using [this example](https://developer.yahoo.com/gemini/#get-started=) I'm able to create and get Objects (create campaign, retrieve campaign) but not able to do Operations like *Update* and *delete*.

I'm getting missing fields error as it's taking it as POST call. For Update / delete I need to make PUT request.

So for that I've added in the following case in YahooOAuth2.class.php file

```
if($method) 
{
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT'));
}
```

Here is the complete function

```
 public function fetch($url, $postdata = "", $auth = "", $headers = "", $method="")
    {
        $curl = curl_init($url);

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); //Temporarily added to disable authenticity of the peer's certificate 

        if ($postdata) {
             if($method) 
             {  
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true);      
             curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT'));
             }
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
        } else {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, false);
        }
        if ($auth) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $auth);
        }
        if ($headers) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        }
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        if (empty($response)) {
            // some kind of an error happened
            die(curl_error($curl));
            curl_close($curl); // close cURL handler
        } else {
            $info = curl_getinfo($curl);
            curl_close($curl); // close cURL handler
            if ($info['http_code'] != 200 && $info['http_code'] != 201) {
                echo "Received error: " . $info['http_code']. "\n";
                echo "Raw response:".$response."\n";
                die();
            }
        }
        return $response;
    }
```

When I run the file I'm getting the following response

> object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (4) { ["errIndex"]=> int(-1) ["code"]=> string(28) "E10000_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR" ["message"]=> string(12) "invalid JSON" ["description"]=> string(0) "" } } ["response"]=> NULL ["timestamp"]=> string(18) "2015-07-20 6:21:14" }

It's working fine for **create** and **retrieve** but not for **update** and **delete**.

Here is the example file to make Update Campaign.

```
<?php

require "YahooOAuth2.class.php"; 

#Your Yahoo API consumer key & secret with access to Gemini data 

define("CONSUMER_KEY","sdfsadfw23r23423rsdf--");
define("CONSUMER_SECRET","234234sdfwr");
$redirect_uri="http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
$gemini_api_endpoint="https://api.admanager.yahoo.com/v1/rest";
//$gemini_api_endpoint="https://sandbox-api.admanager.yahoo.com/v1/rest";

$oauth2client=new YahooOAuth2();

if (isset($_GET['code'])){
    $code=$_GET['code'];    
} 
else {
    $code=0;
}

if($code){
     $token=$oauth2client->get_access_token(CONSUMER_KEY,CONSUMER_SECRET,$redirect_uri,$code);
     $headers= array('Authorization: Bearer '.$token,'Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json');
     $url=$gemini_api_endpoint."/campaign/";
    $data = array("id"=>12356,"budget"=> 500);  
     $postdata = json_encode($data);
     $method = "PUT";
     $resp=$oauth2client->fetch($method, $url,$postdata,$auth="",$headers);
      $jsonResponse = json_decode( $resp);
      var_dump($jsonResponse);
}
else {
    # no valid access token available, go to authorization server 
    header("HTTP/1.1 302 Found");
    header("Location: " . $oauth2client->getAuthorizationURL(CONSUMER_KEY,$redirect_uri));
    exit;
}

?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Is there any method to do Update/delete operations or did I miss anything from above? I found no example from [Yahoo Gemini Documentation](https://developer.yahoo.com/gemini) for Updating Objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've ended up like this. In the YahooOAuth2.class.php file . I've just added the following code under fetch function.

```
if ($postdata) 
{
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
if($method)  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method); // For Update and Delete requests
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
}
```

It's working like a charm. I hope it helps someone

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the order of statements as the last `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` implies `CURLOPT_POST` as pointed out in the docs here http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS.html. So you'll need to override that with a `PUT` as follows:

```
if($method) 
{
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
  curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('X-HTTP-Method-Override: PUT'));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've changed it, but still getting the same error. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I'm getting the following response
>object(stdClass)#2 (3) { ["errors"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#3 (4) { ["errIndex"]=> int(-1) ["code"]=> string(28) "E10000_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR" ["message"]=> string(12) "invalid JSON" ["description"]=> string(0) "" } } ["response"]=> NULL ["timestamp"]=> string(18) "2015-07-20 6:21:14" }

Comment: Seems that your data is invalid; the authentication is ok now

Comment: yeah, I recheked my input data, I'm giving correct JSON format and passing required params. don't know what's going on. For example, to update campaign I'm sending valid existing id.

Comment: In a PUT you'd typically have to provide the complete object contents, not just the element you want to modify

Comment: Infact I tried that way too. let me check again. Thanks

Comment: I've followed [Update existing campaigns](https://developer.yahoo.com/gemini/guide/campaigns.html) and did the same.